# Malloc Assertion Issue

Tags: c, file, malloc, valgrind

I'm trying to initialize a struct:

```
struct OpenFile
{
    unsigned short inuse;
    unsigned short inode;
    unsigned short currpos;
    unsigned short currbloqueenmemoria;
    unsigned char* buffer;
    unsigned short* indirectBuff;
};
```

With a function:

```
void inicializa_openfiles(){
    int i;
                            printf("Entra incializador\n");
    if(!openfiles_inicializada)
    {                                           printf("Abre\n");
        openfiles = malloc(sizeof(struct OpenFile) * 16);           

        for(i = 3; i < 16; i++)                             
        {
            openfiles[i].inuse = 0;
            openfiles[i].currbloqueenmemoria = -1;
            openfiles[i].buffer = malloc(secboot.sectores_x_bloque * BYTES_SECTOR);
        }
                                    printf("termina\n");
        openfiles_inicializada = 1;
    }
}
```

And I get an assertion error in             openfiles = malloc(sizeof(struct OpenFile) * 16);           , I tried using Valgrind, but I don't know how to detect the problem or how to fix it. Any sugestions? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's what I get with the Valgrind with no extra parameters:

```
==11136== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11136== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11136== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11136== Command: ./shell1
==11136== 
vshell > copy //Test.txt text.txt
Abre y copia
Crea
Revisa existencia
==11136== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==11136==    at 0x4F22350: __read_nocancel (syscall-template.S:81)
==11136==    by 0x40393B: vdreadsector (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x400F39: vdreadseclog (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x401008: test_mapa_bits_nodos_i_en_memoria (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x401588: searchinode (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x401FBF: vdcreat (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x403072: copyuv (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x402DAC: executecmd (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x402BFA: main (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==  Address 0x51fc240 is 0 bytes after a block of size 512 alloc'd
==11136==    at 0x4C2ABBD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==11136==    by 0x400FD2: test_mapa_bits_nodos_i_en_memoria (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x401588: searchinode (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x401FBF: vdcreat (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x403072: copyuv (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x402DAC: executecmd (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x402BFA: main (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:278 (mk_plain_bszB): Assertion 'bszB != 0' failed.
valgrind: This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.


host stacktrace:
==11136==    at 0x3805DAE6: show_sched_status_wrk (m_libcassert.c:319)
==11136==    by 0x3805DBF4: report_and_quit (m_libcassert.c:390)
==11136==    by 0x3805DD76: vgPlain_assert_fail (m_libcassert.c:455)
==11136==    by 0x380688AA: mk_plain_bszB.part.8 (m_mallocfree.c:278)
==11136==    by 0x3806B057: mk_plain_bszB (m_mallocfree.c:302)
==11136==    by 0x3806B057: get_bszB_as_is (m_mallocfree.c:301)
==11136==    by 0x3806B057: get_bszB (m_mallocfree.c:312)
==11136==    by 0x3806B057: vgPlain_arena_malloc (m_mallocfree.c:1739)
==11136==    by 0x3802CC74: vgMemCheck_new_block (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:350)
==11136==    by 0x3802CE47: vgMemCheck_malloc (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:385)
==11136==    by 0x380AF1C5: do_client_request (scheduler.c:1840)
==11136==    by 0x380AF1C5: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1409)
==11136==    by 0x380BDC8C: thread_wrapper (syswrap-linux.c:103)
==11136==    by 0x380BDC8C: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:156)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==11136==    at 0x4C2ABBD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==11136==    by 0x401053: test_nodos_i_en_memoria (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x401592: searchinode (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x401FBF: vdcreat (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x403072: copyuv (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x402DAC: executecmd (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
==11136==    by 0x402BFA: main (in /home/svaejat/Pr8/shell1)
```

EDIT 2:

I followed the trace shown in Valgrind, This are all the functions mentioned:

```
    int vdreadsector(int drive, int head, int cylinder, int sector, int nsecs, char *buffer)
    {
        char filename[20];
        int fp;
        int timecyl,timesec;
        int sl,offset;
        sprintf(filename,"disco%c.vd",(char) drive+'0');
        fp=open(filename,O_RDONLY);
        if(fp==-1)
            return(-1);

        // Valida parámetros
        if(drive<0 || drive>3)
            return(-1);

        if(head<0 || head>=HEADS)
            return(-1);

        if(cylinder<0 || cylinder>=CYLINDERS)
            return(-1);

        if(sector<1 || sector>SECTORS)
            return(-1);

        if(sector+nsecs-1>SECTORS)
            return(-1);

        // Hace el retardo
        timesec=sector-currentsec[drive];
        if(timesec<0)
            timesec+=SECTORS;
        usleep(timesec*1000);
        currentsec[drive]=sector;

        timecyl=abs(currentcyl[drive]-cylinder);
        usleep(timecyl*1000);
        currentcyl[drive]=cylinder;

        // Calcula la posición en el archivo
        sl=cylinder*SECTORS*HEADS+head*SECTORS+(sector-1);
        offset=sl*512;
        lseek(fp,offset,SEEK_SET);
        read(fp,buffer,512*nsecs);
        close(fp);
        return(nsecs);
    }

int vdreadseclog(int sector_logico, int numero_de_sectores, char * buffer)
{
    int cilindro;
    int superficie;
    int sector_fisico;

    if(sector_logico >= 0 && sector_logico < secboot.sectores_logicos_x_unidad)
    {
        /* Calcular ubicación del sector lógico */
        cilindro = sector_logico / (secboot.sectores_fisicos * secboot.superficies);
        superficie = (sector_logico / secboot.sectores_fisicos) % secboot.superficies;
        sector_fisico = (sector_logico % secboot.sectores_fisicos) + 1;

        /* Leer el sector físico en el disco al buffer */
        if(vdreadsector(DISCO_DEFAULT, superficie, cilindro, sector_fisico, numero_de_sectores, buffer) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error en vdreadsector\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Número de sector lógico inválido\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 1;
}

void test_mapa_bits_nodos_i_en_memoria()
{
    /* Sector donde comienza el mapa de bits de nodos i */
    int inicio = secboot.sectores_reservados + 1;
    int i;

    if(!mapa_bits_nodos_i_en_memoria)
    {
        mapa_bits_nodos_i = malloc(secboot.sectores_mapa_bits_nodos_i * BYTES_SECTOR);
        for(i = 0; i < secboot.sectores_mapa_bits_nodos_i + 1; i++)
        {
            vdreadseclog(inicio, 1, mapa_bits_nodos_i + (i * BYTES_SECTOR));
        }
        mapa_bits_nodos_i_en_memoria = 1;
    }
}

int searchinode(char *filename, int firstFileOnDir, int iNodeSearch)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int result;

    /* Si el super bloque no esta en memoria, lo leo del primer sector físico */
    test_secboot_en_memoria();

    /* Si el mapa de bits de nodos i no esta en memoria, lo leo del disco */
    test_mapa_bits_nodos_i_en_memoria();

    /* Si la tabla de nodos i no esta en memoria, la leo del disco */
    test_nodos_i_en_memoria();

    /* Recorre mientras no llegue al final del mapa de bits */
    while(i < (secboot.sectores_mapa_bits_nodos_i * BYTES_SECTOR))
    {
        // Si no está libre, entra
        if(mapa_bits_nodos_i[i] != 0x00)
        {       
            j = 0;

            /* Recorre bit por bit, probando si donde hay un '1' es el nombre
               de archivo que estamos buscando  */
            while(j < 8)
            {
                // Si es uno, verifica si el nombre de archivo es el buscado
                if(mapa_bits_nodos_i[i] & (1<<j))
                {
                    // Si estás buscando el primer archivo de root, regresa el índice
                    if(firstFileOnDir == 1)
                    {
                        return((i * 8) + j);
                    }

                    //nTest
                    if(firstFileOnDir == 2)
                    {
                        if(iNodeSearch < ((i * 8) + j))
                        {
                            return((i * 8) + j);
                        }
                    }

                    // Si es el nombre que buscamos
                    if(strcmp(nodos_i[(i * 8) + j].nombre, filename) == 0)
                    {
                        return((i * 8) + j);
                    }
                }

                j++;
            }
        }

        i++;
    }
    return (-1); /* Llego al final del mapa de bits sin encontrar un sólo bit en cero */
}
```

I think there's a problem with searchinode, searching out of the parameters, but I cant get the hang of it

Comment: What does the assertion say?

Comment: shell1: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

Comment: Looks like heap corruption. Your problem is not in presented code but elsewhere in program. Comment out this section and run it in valgrind without extra parameters, it should report memory misuses.

Comment: @keltar, Where should I look for the reported issues? I posted the reponse in the question

Comment: For what it's worth, [this](http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#2362) seems to be the assertion in the malloc.c code. Agreed with keltar: something else is quite likely off even before this assertion hit.

Comment: Your `malloc()` call appears to be in `test_mapa_bits_nodos_i_en_memoria()` and the fault appears to be in a `read()` call from within the same function, not necessarily in the same invocation, maybe via your functions to read sectors. Unfortunately, you don't seem to be showing us that code.  It is also a good idea to compile with debugging information (usually `-g`); you will get better reports from `valgrind` when you do.

Comment: The Valgrind output gives you the stack trace where you first corrupted memory (that's the first stack trace). Since the access is right after a valid block, with a similar stack trace, I would guess that you have a buffer overflow.

Comment: You might want to consult [this](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.bad-syscall-args) part of the Valgrind manual too. It looks like the buffer allocation went wrong or has been freed. Did you check for NULL?

Comment: Why the **3** in `for(i = 3; i < 16; i++)`?  Doesn't that leave the first 3 array entries uninitialized?

Comment: Why are the first three instances of the struct not initialized?  Where/what is the definition of BYTES_SECTOR?  where/what is the definition of secboot?  what is the current value of secboot.sectores_x_bloque?

Comment: the messages from valgrind are not about the code you displayed.  Please post the actual code that valgrind is complaining about.

Comment: It starts in 3, because I have to leave them reserved by my teachers orders. 
BYTES_SECTOR = 512
secboot.sectores_x_bloque = 4

Comment: @ShaulaMontoya where does this `buffer` comes from? What is its size? Check value of `buffer` at the moment it is being allocated *and* before `read` - it is likely to be changed at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you observe indicates that the hear is *already* corrupted by the moment you call your `malloc`. Your `malloc` call simply *detects* the corruption, it does not *cause* it.

One of the easiest ad-hoc tricks to find the source of corruption is to insert an additional `malloc` call with the same requested memory size (i.e. `sizeof(struct OpenFile) * 16`) somewhere higher upstream in the code. If it fails there as well, you move that extra call higher upstream. If it doesn't fail, you move it downstream. That way you will eventually be able to zero-in on the exact culprit that corrupts the heap. (This might require some creativity to make sure that that extra `malloc` call is executed on the proper iterations of various cycles you might have in your code and/or on the proper invocations of the functions, but it is doable.)

Or you can use valgrind for this purpose. Albeit I find it that in some cases the above ad-hoc procedure proves to be a more efficient approach for finding the source of the corruption, if the failure occurs quickly and you work in an environment that supports quick recompilation of the code.

Comment: I tried this, but still can't find the error. And I can't detect where the memory corruption is occuring